# What is the exact equivalent of this netsh Windows command for MAC? The command is attached in the body

Tags: windows-10, macos, netsh

I want to block all networks from my PC with admin access and make it so that the user cannot reverse the changes. I will use admin access to only white list certain networks that will be visible to the user and all other WiFi networks are blocked. I am blocking all connections in Windows with the following command. Since I am just starting out with MAC, any help in this regard is appreciated.

`netsh wlan add filter permission=denyall networktype=infrastructure`

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Are these networks within the same vicinity? If not, you can enable admin authorization for changing networks for a simpler solution. If not, the management profile route is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to approach it professionally use dedicated device management API:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement
Then you can deploy profiles to device across whole organization via commercial MDM/EMM or free Apple Configurator 2. In past there was also free of charge Apple own MDM solution available as virtual machine. You can start here:
https://support.apple.com/pl-pl/guide/mdm/welcome/1/web

If you really want to script around user dedicated commands you can look at:

> 'Wifi=`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport --getinfo | grep " SSID" | awk '{print $2}'`

and

> networksetup -setairportnetwork [interface] [router SSID] [password]

then once a few seconds check network and potentially disconnect.